# Is 育ち行く normally used?

Tags: verbs

Are there any situations in which the verb 育ち行く is used?  I checked it up in www.tangorin.com and http://jisho.org/ and in both I found the definition, but not a single example of its use.

Comment: Tangorin and jisho use the same source ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an unfamiliar word, though I'm not sure if it's "normally" used.

This is a compound verb of `育つ` "grow up" + `行く` "go away; get further and further", and the meaning is transparent. The `-行く` is appended to 連用形 of verbs of state change, to make literary expressions of similar nuance to `-て行く` e.g. `去り行く` (老兵は死なず、ただ去り行くのみ "[Old soldiers never die; they just fade away.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Douglas_MacArthur#Farewell_address_to_Congress_.281951.29)"), `移り行く`, `散り行く`, `変わり行く` etc. These words are hardly used outside attributive nowadays, and don't conjugate, either.

I found many examples in Google that related to `育ちゆく体とわたし` (lit. "My growing-up body and I"), which seemingly is a sub-curriculum of P.E. on sex education.

Comment: When I hear 「育ち行く」 in conversation, it sounds formal. If I would make a speech and have it loftier, I may use this word.